# Dumping protocol-buffers file to stdout to debug/investigate?

Tags: dump, protocol-buffers, protoc

I have a `.proto` file and a `pbf` (protocol buffers file). Is there anyway I can "dump" the pbf file into some sort of verbose human readable output format? I just want to be able to look inside it and see the data in there.

Ideally I'm looking for an open source cli tool that runs on linux that'll work something like:

```
commandname spec.proto data.pbf
```

Does this exist? I tried `cat data.pbf | protoc --decode_raw` but I got a message of `Failed to parse input.` on many files that I am very confident are valid. Would it be easy to write a programme that will do this? If so, how?

*(I am new to protocol buffers, I'm sorry if this is a silly or nonsensical question)*

Answer (score 1):

OpenStreetMap's `.pbf` is not actually a pure-protobuf format. See my answer to your other question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35384238/2686899