# "Failed to parse input" from Google protocol buffers protoc command for ``--decode_raw``

Tags: protocol-buffers, protoc

I have a [google protobuf file](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) from [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org), specifically I have the 1.4MB [Liechtenstein country extract from Geofabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/liechtenstein.html). The `protoc` command says it "write the raw tag/values to stdout" with the `--decode_raw` option. However I keep getting this error:

```
$ cat liechtenstein-latest.osm.pbf | protoc --decode_raw
Failed to parse input.
```

I have compiled and installed the protobuf library direct from Google, version 2.6.1 which is the current one.

This file is valid, various OpenStreetMap tools that read pbf files ([osm2pgsql](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql), [osmosis](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis)) can read it fine.

What could be wrong? How can I get `--decode_raw` to work? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OpenStreetMap `.osm.pbf` format is *not* a raw protocol buffer. The format is documented here:

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PBF_Format

Key quote:

> The format is a repeating sequence of:
>
> - int4: length of the BlobHeader message in network byte order
> - serialized BlobHeader message
> - serialized Blob message (size is given in the header)

So you need to read four bytes first, interpret them as an integer (big-endian), then read that many bytes and parse as a `BlobHeader`, and that in turn will tell you how many bytes to read and parse as a `Blob`.

The `protoc` tool will not do this automatically since it doesn't know this format. Probably there is an OSM-specific tool out there that you can use.