# Cannot parse a protocol buffers file in python when using the correct .proto file

Tags: python, openstreetmap, protocol-buffers

*(see update at bottom)*

[Tilemaker](https://github.com/systemed/tilemaker) is an [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org) programme to generate [Mapbox vector tiles](https://www.mapbox.com/developers/vector-tiles/) (which are themselves [protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) (pbf) files) from an OSM pbf data file. I have compiled it and used it to create a directory of vector tiles. I cannot parse those files in Python.

I created the vector tiles with:

```
tilemaker input.pbf --output=tiles/
```

Then I created a simple python programme, based on [Google's Protocol Buffers Python Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial#writing-a-message) in this way:

Compiling the `.proto` files:

```
mkdir py
touch py/__init__.py
protoc --proto_path=include --python_out=./py ./include/osmformat.proto
protoc --proto_path=include --python_out=./py ./include/vector_tile.proto
```

This python programme `pyread.py` doesn't work:

```
import sys
import py.vector_tile_pb2

with open(sys.argv[1]) as fp:
    pbf_file_contents = fp.read()

tile = py.vector_tile_pb2.Tile()
tile.ParseFromString(pbf_file_contents)
```

This is the error when trying to run it:

```
$ python pyread.py ./tiles/13/3932/2588.pbf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyread.py", line 8, in <module>
    tile.ParseFromString(pbf_file_contents)
  File "/home/rory/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/message.py", line 186, in ParseFromString
    self.MergeFromString(serialized)
  File "/home/rory/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py", line 841, in MergeFromString
    if self._InternalParse(serialized, 0, length) != length:
  File "/home/rory/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py", line 866, in InternalParse
    new_pos = local_SkipField(buffer, new_pos, end, tag_bytes)
  File "/home/rory/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/decoder.py", line 827, in SkipField
    return WIRETYPE_TO_SKIPPER[wire_type](buffer, pos, end)
  File "/home/rory/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/decoder.py", line 797, in _RaiseInvalidWireType
    raise _DecodeError('Tag had invalid wire type.')
google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Tag had invalid wire type.
```

The `protoc` command is from the protcol buffers library. I downloaded the latest release (2.6.1) from Google's page (which links to Github) and compiled & installed it. That protoc invocation is just like what the [Tilemaker Makefile does](https://github.com/systemed/tilemaker/blob/15a18afca342362a7f3d780c7ca64b1c30552e3d/Makefile#L20).

What's going on? How can I read this protocol buffers file in python?

---

**UPDATE** Further investigation makes me think that one of my assumptions might be wrong. Namely, that the `tilemaker` command has produced a valid protobuf file. I got some [vector tiles from Mapzen](https://mapzen.com/projects/vector-tiles/), which should have the same format and very similar data. *But* this format works with the python `pyread.py` command, and with `protoc --decode_raw` and `protoc --decode=vector_tile.Tile ./include/vector_tile.proto`. Hence I think the problem is with the file I was looking at.

Comment: Does protobuffer from OpenStreetMap have the same version as the protoc used to generate the .py?

Comment: In this example. the Tilemaker programme's Makefile calls the `protoc` command on my machine to produce C++ files form a `.proto` file. I am using the same `protoc` binary, and the same `.proto` files to produce python files, and it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you on Windows? If so, you need to open in binary mode. `open(filename, "rb")`. (It's a good idea to do this on all systems, but it only really matters on Windows.)

Comment: @KentonVarda I'm on Ubuntu Linux, not Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that OpenStreetMap's `.pbf` format is **not** a raw protobuf. See my answer to your other question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35384238/2686899

Comment: Thank you for your insight re: the OSM pbf format. That makes sense. However in this case, the result is in [MapBox Vector Tiles format](https://github.com/mapbox/vector-tile-spec), not [OSM PBF](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PBF_Format). And [the latest (2.1) spec](https://github.com/mapbox/vector-tile-spec/tree/master/2.1) implies that it's a pure protocol buffers file.

Comment: @Rory OK, so does `protoc --decode_raw < file` work with this file? The error you gave suggests the input is not a protobuf at all (not even with a different type).

Comment: See the update I made to the question. `protoc --decode_raw` didn't work on that file. But it (and my programme) work on another file that also should of the same format. Hence you must be right. That file isn't a valid protobuf file.

Answer (score 0):

If you use tilemaker with default config, probably the tile is gzipped(`compress=gzip`):
https://github.com/systemed/tilemaker/blob/master/docs/CONFIGURATION.md#json-configuration

Try unzip your tile by the following command:

```bash
<tile.protoc | gunzip | protoc --decode_raw
```