# Library to read, generate or validate protocol buffer spec?

Tags: protocol-buffers

What's a smart way to generate and validate a protocol buffer spec? Is there any library (binding?) for the protoc file format, maybe java or python?

Just to be clear, I know that after my code generates a protocol buffer specification it will be fed to protoc for generating language-specific binding code.  It's straightforward for me to invoke protoc to validate a generated spec (just check exit code etc.), but I thought maybe there's a better way.

The only vaguely related thing I could find is [Cannot parse a protocol buffers file in python when using the correct .proto file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35367800/cannot-parse-a-protocol-buffers-file-in-python-when-using-the-correct-proto-fil)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably just invoke the `protoc` binary and check the exit code, because that command line interface is likely to be more stable across versions than a library interface.

However, all the relevant functionality is available in `libprotoc.so`. As a starting point, you can see the `protoc` main program here, which is beautifully short: https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/compiler/main.cc

I expect you could pretty much copy that to your own project and link against `libprotoc.so`.

Comment: thanks @jpa seems the short answer to my question is "no" there's no helper library.

Comment: @chrisinmtown I'm not quite sure what kind of a helper library you were hoping for, though.